# Mate-in-25 tsumeshogi

Tags: no-computers, chess, shogi

This is apparently the first [shogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi)-related question on this site! Yay!

Anyway, this is a **mate-in-25 [tsumeshogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsume_shogi)**. Sente (the player with the pieces pointing up) is to move and *by an uninterrupted series of checks* checkmate the opponent in 25 moves against best defence. (Shogi literature defines a move as one piece move or one drop by either player *individually*, so 25 moves means 13 moves by Sente and 12 by the opponent Gote alternating).

[image]

The position's [SFEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi_notation#SFEN) is `l1g6/kss6/2S6/1+BP3R2/9/9/9/6K2/9 b SNLrb3g3n2l17p 1`. I created this tsumeshogi from a [full game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZudasTsfXk) I saw on YouTube.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what software are you using to generate the image for this game?

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem I just went to [Lishogi](https://lishogi.org).

Comment: Thanks! For those interested, [here is the position imported into Lishogi's board editor.](https://lishogi.org/editor/l1g6/kss6/2S6/1+BP3R2/9/9/9/6K2/9_b_SNLrb3g3n2l17p_1)